# Necessary jar files for basic sturts 2 application

Tags: java, jsp, jar

I am just new to Sturts 2 Web Application Development. I started with basic hello world Sturt application. Its working fine, but m still wondering that what jar files are needed for what kind of Sturts 2 application, or at least for a basic sturt application.

Comment: Or... you could just use one of the maven struts archetypes and see for yourself which archetype requires which jar files.

Comment: M using Eclipse Juno IDE, tell me is maven struts archetypes a plugin or something? If so then guide me to install it and later on use it. Thnx

Comment: Maven is a build tool. It helps to resolve all your jar dependencies. You need not have to add one by one. If you specify important jars it would add all other needed by itself and much more. See this for a Struts example with maven http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-hello-world-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that have a working Java web application, lets add the minimal required Struts 2 framework Jar files to our web application's class path. And copy these Jar files from the lib folder of the Struts 2 download to the WEB-INF/lib folder in our web application.

Find and copy to WEB-INF\lib these files (note X.X.X.X.jar refers to the version number):

1. **commons-fileupload-X.X.X.jar**
2. **commons-io-X.X.X.jar**
3. **commons-logging-X.X.X.jar**
4. **commons-logging-api.X.X.jar**
5. **freemarker-X.X.X.jar**
6. **ognl-X.X.X.jar**
7. **struts2-core-X.X.X.X.jar**
8. **xwork-core-X.X.X.jar**
9. **javassist-3.7.ga.jar (new for Struts versions 2.2.1 and higher)**

You can see from the above that the Struts 2 core jar depends on several other artifacts. As we add additional Struts 2 features in future tutorials, we'll need to add additional Struts 2 jar files and other transitive dependencies.

[use this link](http://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/struts2/basic-struts2-project-setup#Step1)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add one more jar file *xwork2.jar* I think this is important jar.